# uploading an image to server using Alamofire Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, urlsession

I am trying to upload an image to server , but its showing its not current format , I have seen so many solutions in stack , but haven't work on my code .

here is the screenshot of my postman : [postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoUX2.png)  for auth:
[Screenshot of Authorization page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlNLR.png)

code I have tried with Alamofire : `

```
func upload(image: Data, to url: Alamofire.URLRequestConvertible, params: [String: Any]) {
        AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in
            for (key, value) in params {
                if let temp = value as? String {
                    multiPart.append(temp.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
                if let temp = value as? Int {
                    multiPart.append("\(temp)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
                if let temp = value as? NSArray {
                    temp.forEach({ element in
                        let keyObj = key + "[]"
                        if let string = element as? String {
                            multiPart.append(string.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: keyObj)
                        } else
                            if let num = element as? Int {
                                let value = "\(num)"
                                multiPart.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: keyObj)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            multiPart.append(image, withName: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }, with: url)
            .uploadProgress(queue: .main, closure: { progress in
                //Current upload progress of file
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: { data in
                //Do what ever you want to do with response
            })
    }

`
```

now I need help to upload the image using url session or Alamofire .
need help about parameter to url: also.

the url is : "http://germanbutcher.easyservice.xyz/backend/api/v1/users/33/photo"
thanks in advance

Comment: Replace multiPart.append(image, withName: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png") with multiPart.append(image, withName: "photo", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")

Comment: still its not working . do you know how I will do it with url session ?

Comment: Try using [MultipartMediaUploadManager](https://github.com/udbhateja/MultipartMediaUploadManager) and see if it still works.

Comment: in your code , here is an error called :" '_' can only appear in a pattern or on the left side of an assignment " - on switch case section

Comment: This error is from Alamofire. Maybe your version od Alamofire is different than than the one used. I am using 4.9.1. Either use this version or rectify the error by changing the code. It will be just a minor syntax change.